# Restricted access to Java package

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, package

I have commands fired by GUI buttons, for example: Start and Abort.  These commands are executed in the actionPerformed method after a button click.  The GUI and commands are in package A.  In package B I have a class that calls a method from an external library.

Example in package B:

```
class Control {
    void start() {
      extLib.start();
    }

    void abort() {
      extLib.abort();
    }
  }
```

Classes in package A don't have access to classes in package B.  How can I execute methods from the Control class in my commands?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's wrong with import packageB.*; ?

Comment: I would assume this methods are either a) accessible via another class which you should be using, or b) hidden for a good reason.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes but class Control is public and its methods are public, so what is the "real" problem in importing ?

Comment: @BigMike I assumed it was `extLib.start();` which is package local.

Comment: @PeterLawrey probably, but that's sounds fishy. If I can instantiate a Control I should be able to use it even if it's using some private exotic. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear.  Exactly what doesn't work when you do something like this? Control c = new Control(); ...  c.start(); ... c.abort();

Comment: Package rules are like this, classes in package A must not instantiate classes from package B. Package A contains certain kind of class and package B other kind and there should be not dependency from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

In `class A` add this `import yourpackage.*;` where `class B` is available.

Now you can refer to your Control class by doing this.

```
Control c = new Control ();
c.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the package in the Control class, but do not have access to its methods `start()` and `abort()`, as the criteria for access to the methods without modifiers is package level. You must define the public methods, or alternatively protected by defining the other class as subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the public access modifier for classes in package B public instead of the default modifier!

Answer (score 0):

My question was probably unclear or uncomplete, sorry for that.
Here is what I did
In package B:

```
package b.startup

public class Initialize {
  public Initialize() {
    CmdFactory.getInstance().setControlAdapter(new ControlAdapter());
  }
}
```

```
package b.control
public class ControlAdapter implements Control {
  public void start() { extLib.start() };
  public void abort() { extLib.abort() };
}
```

In package A

```
package a.control
  public interface Control {
    void start();
    void abort();
  }
```

```
package a.cmd
    public class StartCmd extends Command {
      public void execute(/* Some parameters */) {
        CmdFactory.getInstance.getControlAdapter().start(/* Some parameters */);
      }
    }
```

```
package a.factory
public class CmdFactory {
  Control control;
  // Constructor for default control
  // Getter and Setter for control.
}
```

Class in package A don't call method from class in package B.  Pretty simple, but my solution use Singleton and I wanted to avoid it as well as static method.